# autopilot installation error

Tags: juju, openstack

I am trying the autopilot install using instructions from
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud

Autopilot consistently fails at point where the status display says `registering against landscape`

The key seems to be when the script is running the configure-landscape command.  This text is returned in the `~/.cloud-install/commands.log`:

```
line 126, in run_query\n assert r.status_code == 200\nAssertionError\n', 'status': 1}
```

We would like to stick to the script to find out why the official instructions are not working.

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to offer.